# How to control ParallelSuite thread count?

Tags: java, testing, junit, concurrency

I have following code:

```
@RunWith(ParallelSuite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Test1.class,
        Test2.class,
        Test3.class,
        Test4.class,
        Test5.class,
        Test6.class,
        Test7.class})
public class ParallelRunner {
}
```

I ran it and figured out that only 3 test run in parallel. These test anough long - 15+ seconds

Is it OS scheduler issue or junit thread pool limit?

How can I configure thread pool limit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's backed by a `ForkedThreadPool` which is work stealing.

```
static ForkJoinPool setUpForkJoinPool() {
    int numThreads;
    try {
        String configuredNumThreads = System.getProperty("maxParallelTestThreads");
        numThreads = Math.max(2, Integer.parseInt(configuredNumThreads));
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        numThreads = Math.max(2, runtime.availableProcessors());
    }
    ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory threadFactory = pool -> {
        if (pool.getPoolSize() >= pool.getParallelism()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            ForkJoinWorkerThread thread = ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);
            thread.setName("JUnit-" + thread.getName());
            return thread;
        }
    };
    return new ForkJoinPool(numThreads, threadFactory, null, false);
}
```

Effectively can set `maxParallelTestThreads`, else it will back to max of the number of processors, or two threads min.

Comment: 1.Where can I configure it? 2. Is it default jvm forkJoin thread pool?

Comment: the pasted code is from the `ParallelSuite`, you need to pass the `maxParallelTestThreads` if you want to configure it, or set it manually in the test. Else it will be maxNumberOfCores or 2 whatever is higher.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `ParallelComputer` you can find following method:

```
private static Runner parallelize(Runner runner) {
        if (runner instanceof ParentRunner) {
            ((ParentRunner)runner).setScheduler(new RunnerScheduler() {
                private final ExecutorService fService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

                public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
                    this.fService.submit(childStatement);
                }

                public void finished() {
                    try {
                        this.fService.shutdown();
                        this.fService.awaitTermination(9223372036854775807L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException var2) {
                        var2.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        return runner;
    }
```

we need to replace this:

```
private final ExecutorService fService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

I just copy pasted `ParallelComputer` class code and replaced this line with:

```
private final ExecutorService fService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD_COUNT);
```